# Is it possible to upload videos on specific channel through youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to upload videos on a specific channel through Youtube API?

I am just able to upload videos on main account. We have created some channels using business names. But, I could not find any way to upload videos on those channels so far using API.

On main account, the profile is using a human name. We need to use business name and the channels have been created using business names under the main youtube account. I uploaded a video manually too. But, we need to upload the videos using API on those business channels.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you get authorized for that account, you can upload to that account too.
- If you are using Google+ to manage all those accounts, [you can read here.](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api_24.html) (This is also suggested way to manage multiple channels with one login name.)
- If you are a content owner that is managing all these channels, then you can use Content ID API.

Comment: It worked! I particularly created a new username and password from Google plus manage pages which is still under main account. Then, I used the new username and password in my script and it started uploading directly on my channel. Thank you so much.

Comment: The 'you can read here' link is broken. Is this solution still accurate and up-to-date?